# How to edit a gradle file in a Unity3D project (Android platform)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I am building an android app in unity and i want to see the dependencies in the gradle file in my Unity project
But it basically has only this sigle parameter BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS surrounded with two asterisks on each side
I have no idea what this paramer is, what is its value?
I googled and came up short
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Unity figures out the dependencies at build-time.  That's a placeholder for the Unity build process to fill out that section when it creates the Android project.    If you want to see the final results, build an APK and then pull it into Android Studio.